# Countermeasures to prevent integral cryptanalysis against 4-rounds AES

Tags: aes, cryptanalysis, s-boxes, arx

Integral cryptanalysis against 4-rounds AES is practical ([Security of the AES with a Secret S-box](https://eprint.iacr.org/2015/144.pdf)). I did two experiments in order to find the impact and remove the integral distinguisher  of 4 rounds:

- I replaced key addition $\oplus$ with $\boxplus$ (mod 32 bit)
- I replaced the sbox with S1 Sbox in Clefia cipher  (same differential and linear probability).

but the integral distinguisher is still present.

Further reading lead me to find that BelT cipher ([Finding Integral Distinguishers with Ease](https://eprint.iacr.org/2018/688.pdf)) has no integral distinguisher after three rounds.

**Questions:**

- Where is the exploitable integral structure in AES-like?
- What countermeasures are taken to remove integral distinguisher?
- What is the advantage taken in BelT cipher?

Comment: What's wrong with more than 4 rounds, per common wisdom?

Comment: Nothing wrong but can we do better with less rounds

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question may be theoretically interesting.

However, it looks to me strongly likely that the nice diffusion properties of AES using operations of order $4$ ShiftRows) and matrix ($4\times 4$) multiplication on vectors of dimension $4$ (MixColumns) are the reason for the existence of these attacks and changing these properties may well require more rounds for security.

The requirement that these operations be one-to-one, in the absence of a feistel structure, means that the SPN structure may also need to be dumped in order to avoid 4 round integral cryptanalysis.